# tick label positions for matplotlib 3D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to work out how to set/correct the position of tick labels for a 3D matplotlib plot. Tick labels do not align with the ticks. The issue seems to be especially prominent when many tick labels are required.

I have modified an example (http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/polys3d_demo.html) from the matplotlib documentation to illustrate my question.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
from matplotlib.colors import colorConverter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

cc = lambda arg: colorConverter.to_rgba(arg, alpha=0.6)

xs = np.arange(0, 10, 0.4)
verts = []
zs = np.arange(50)
for z in zs:
    ys = np.ones(len(xs))*z
    ys[0], ys[-1] = 0, 0
    verts.append(list(zip(xs, ys)))

poly = PolyCollection(verts,facecolor='c')
poly.set_alpha(0.7)
ax.add_collection3d(poly, zs=zs, zdir='y')

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_xlim3d(0, 10)
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_ylim3d(-1, len(zs))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(zs)))
labels = {}
for l_c in zs:
    labels[l_c] = 'This Looks Bad'
ax.set_yticklabels(labels,rotation=-15)
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_zlim3d(0, ys.max())

plt.show()
```

[image]

So the question is: how can I get the tick labels to align with the tick positions?

Answer (score 17):

By using these alignments, I get much better placements:

```
ax.set_yticklabels(labels,rotation=-15,
                   verticalalignment='baseline',
                   horizontalalignment='left')
```

I've modified the example with less tick markers so you can see the placement:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Hooked. The problem is that I need to have all the tick labels there (there are at least 50), so using less tick markers is not an option. The misalignment is considerably more prominent with more labels. Even using variants of your solution (and that of @Rutgers), the labels do not look aligned.

Comment: @random.me You can always reduce the font size of the labels, but you still have the fundamental problem of two much text and too little space!

Comment: @random.me Do you need the _ticks_ or the _text_?

Comment: @tcaswell I need tick labels. Which will be text.

Comment: @Hooked Yes, font size can be reduced, in my problem, the figure can be quite large, and the font size quite small, so the space issue is not too troublesome.

Comment: @random.me The figure size was reduced since the code you originally posted had a syntax error (see the edit). I reduced it so that the screenshots were not too large. As an aside, you really should upvote the answers that are helpful and select a correct answer. The original question about alignment _has_ been answered, it might be nice to ask a _new_ question about techniques for cramming many labels onto a plot.

Comment: @Hooked Re. the edit: for me, both `figure(figsize=(10,10))` and `figure(figsize(10,10))` work. Is the latter a syntax error? Re. your aside: both answers are helpful (just up-voted), but I don't believe the original question is solved. When I revert to `figsize=(20,20)`, neither of the solutions result in the correct/desired alignment. I would happily accept an answer that results in the desired alignment. Perhaps I should return the code in the original question to  `figure(figsize=(20,20))`, so that the problem is observable - what do you think?

Answer (score 6):

They do align, but with the horizontal position centered at the tick. Because of the 3D view this makes them appear a bit below where you would expect them to be. The effect is not related to the amount of ticks but to the width.

Specifically setting the alignment will help. Try adding:

```
ax.set_yticklabels(labels,rotation=-15, va='center', ha='left')
```

Play around a bit with the different alignments to see which you prefer, i think you're after ha='left'.

Reducing the padding, distance from the tick, might also help.

[image]

Comment: As a note to the OP: `va` is synomous with `verticalalignment` as in my example. The same holds for `ha` and `horizontalalignment`.

Comment: Yes, thanks for clarifying that, the abbreviations are bliss when typing them a lot. :)

Comment: Thanks @Rutger. I guess this is the best that can be done. I'd already played around with these (ha, va) and nearly got what I want. It works better on this toy example than on the actual problem I am trying to solve. Could you give an example of how to reduce the padding? Maybe add to your existing answer.

Comment: I was thinking of something like `ax.tick_params(axis='y', pad=30)`, but it turns out that only works for 2D plots. Could you clarify what you find "misalignment" as you mentioned in response to Hooked. I think there perfectly aligned. Think of a rectangular box around the rotated label, and imagine a point on each of the corners and four between those points. The question is then which of those 8 points do want to be placed at the position where the ticklabel is (which is padded away from the actual tick).

Comment: @RutgerKassies Yes, I was trying things like that also, but did not have any success. Actually, the original post was edited to make the figure smaller - it was originally `figsize=(20,20)`. At this scale the misalignment with both current answers is still there. To answer your question: I would like the line through the center of the imagined rectangular box, that passes along the horizontal axis, to line up with the tick marker. And I would like the gap between the label and tick to be smaller, ideally controllable.

Comment: If you don't want to be required to give a fixed label text, this worked for me: `plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), verticalalignment='baseline', horizontalalignment='left')`

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the pad argument as negative in the tick_params options for each axis. Like this:

```
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', pad=-3)
```

This might help to adjust the distance between tick labels and axis.