# Badly Aligned 3D Labels - Matplotlib

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, plot, 3d

I'm creating 3D animations of scatter plots with matplotlib and i'm finding it difficult to get the tick-labels aligned with tick marks.

[image: A screen grab from the plot]

You can see that the tick labels, particularly the y axis ticks, do not look like they align with the tick marks. I've seen the solution here: [tick label positions for matplotlib 3D plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16061349/tick-label-positions-for-matplotlib-3d-plot) but it doesn't work for me as I don't want to set the labels manually as I'm using FuncFormatter to format my tick labels (so I can't use ax.set_ylabels(...)). How can I align them whilst using funcformatter? The relevant section of code:

```
def kilometer(x,pos):
label=x/1000
return label

formatter=mtick.FuncFormatter(kilometer)

# Data sourcing function
def getData(reader):
    x=[]
    y=[]
    z=[]
    j=0
    for row in reader:
        t=float(row[0])
        x.append(float(row[1]))
        y.append(float(row[2]))
        z.append(float(row[3]))
        j+=1
        if j==particleNo: break
    return t,x,y,z

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i, fig, reader):
    #fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=1.0)
    if i<rowsToPlot:
        ax.cla()
        x=[]
        y=[]
        z=[]
        t,x,y,z=getData(reader)
        timeTitle=ax.text2D(0.2, 0.9, "Time = %.2e s" % t,      horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='top',transform=ax.transAxes,fontsize=15)
        scat=ax.scatter(x,y,z,s=5)
        ax.scatter(x, y, s=2, alpha=0.05, c='r', zs=zmin, zdir='z')
        ax.scatter(y, z, s=2, alpha=0.05, c='r', zs=xmin, zdir='x')
        ax.scatter(x, z, s=2, alpha=0.05, c='r', zs=ymax, zdir='y')
        ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
        ax.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
        ax.set_zlim(zmin, zmax)
        ax.set_xlabel('\n$x$ [km]\n')
        ax.set_ylabel('\n$y$ [km]\n')
        ax.set_zlabel('\n$z$ [km]\n')
        ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
        ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
        ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
        ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', rotation=-15, verticalalignment='baseline',horizontalalignment='left')
        return timeTitle, scat,
```

Comment: Can't you first `ax.get_yticklabels()`, then put that in `ax.set_yticklabels()` along with the necessary rotation angles and such?

Comment: Just as ha='center' is way shorter then horizontalalignment='center', you can also write va='baseline' in place of verticalalignment='baseline'

Comment: Never worked with 3d graphs but does changing horizontalalignment='left' to horizontalalignment='center' work?