# How to align x or y tick labels to tick direction in 3d subplot?

Tags: matplotlib, data-visualization

Basically I've seen the question in the link [tick label positions for matplotlib 3D plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16061349/tick-label-positions-for-matplotlib-3d-plot)

and it has solutions like

```
ax.set_yticklabels(labels,rotation=-15,
                   verticalalignment='baseline',
                   horizontalalignment='left')
```

The case is that set_yticklabels does not seem to have a method for 3d subplots.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: This is pretty unclear. The linked question **is** a 3d plot. So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: The x and y labels are typically aligned to the base plane.If it has grids drawn on it., I want the labels to be automatically in line to it, even at different angles of the 3d view.

Comment: Yes, but the accepted answer shows how to do it.