# matplotlib 3d: moving tick's label

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to move tick labels in Matplot3dlib like this?
[image]

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.outer(np.linspace(-2, 2, 30), np.ones(30))
y = x.copy().T # transpose
z = np.cos(x ** 2 + y ** 2)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z,cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')
ax.set_title('Surface plot')
plt.show()
```

There are [some ways using pad parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16061349/tick-label-positions-for-matplotlib-3d-plot).
However, I want to move more precisely like figure in the link above.
Any help appreciated.

-- Addition --

When I changing PAD parameter like the code below, the tick's label is more closer to the axis. However, I want to move it a little bit more to -x direction.
[tick's label position changing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfByu.jpg)

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.outer(np.linspace(-2, 2, 30), np.ones(30))
y = x.copy().T # transpose
z = np.cos(x ** 2 + y ** 2)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z,cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')
ax.set_title('Surface plot')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', pad=-5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: In the image, there are arrows in four directions. In which direction do you want to move the axis?

Comment: And by how much? Please post an image with at least an approximate expected result.

Comment: Why would you want to move the labels ALONG the axis? A label is associated with a tick for a reason.

Comment: @r-beginners, The More detailed situation is added. I want to move the labels to get more alignment.

Comment: I think a better option is to highlight a particular gridline instead, then readers will have an easier time to figure out the alignment themselves.
Inspiration could maybe be gained from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684448/how-to-color-a-specific-gridline-tickline-in-3d-matplotlib-scatter-plot-figure

Comment: The visual impression you have will change with the viewing angle. So, any manual adjustment in one view will cause problems in another. Having said that `plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), ha="right")` probably achieves your aim in the current view.

Comment: @Mr.T, Thanks it works!! and "va" parameter also helps me. But I am still curious about it. It seems that the "pad" parameter moves the labels to a certain axis, for example, the pad parameter in x label moves it to (-y, -z) direction. Is there a way to move it only y or z direction?